# Tidy causing bad spacing issues (JTidy)

Tags: java, html, xml, xhtml, tidy

We are using JTidy to clean up some html for sax processing.  We've had a lot of trouble around spacing issues as shown in this example:

Html

```
<i>stack<span
class="bold">overflow</span></i>
```

which outputs "stackoverflow"

But...

Post JTidy

```
<i>stack
<span
class="bold">overflow</span></i>
```

which outputs "stack overflow" (note the new space)

Anyone have any advice to fix/handle this better.  I've been through all the Tidy/JTidy settings and don't see anything to account for this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this simple example doesn't really show the issue.  The actual issue was that Tidy/JTidy was using a default wrapping setting which was causing the above issue (and other various spacing issues) when there were very long attribute values.

Everything was fixed with:

```
 jtidy.setWraplen(0);
 jtidy.setWrapAttVals(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

What settings are you using? Executing JTidy from the command line using its default settings on the snippet you posted prints this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy, see www.w3.org">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<i>stack<span class="bold">overflow</span></i>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Agreed.  This simple example does work.  Our actual content has much longer lists of style attributes, which pointed me to the "wrapping" settings of tidy.  Sure enough, that fixed the problem.